# Working directly on the Heroku app

Tags: git, heroku

I have now created, installed and tested the Heroku. 
As it is all running through Git, how is it to work with daily?

When I am developing my web app, I am constantly wanting to test and see the outcome. As I am developing alone and on my local machine, I did not really need to use Git.

As for now, with Git, i need to

```
add .
commit -m "update"
git push heroku master
```

To get the updated code working on my heroku app.

This leads me to that you are not supposed to develop and live test on the heruko app? I mean because it is not working like a FTP server where you just can open the file and edit it, save and see the changes. But it has to go through git.

So I need to run on my local wampserver, and then only pushing "complete" updates (new features, fixes) to the heruko app?

If yes to above, the next thing is my application is using a MySQL database. I understood that i need to convert it to heroku postgreSQL, fine I can do that once - but if i change the table struture what then? I need to convert again?

Maybe using Heroku does not suit me?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this addon in Heroku to support MySQL: https://addons.heroku.com/cleardb

I wouldn't recommend you to be using different databases in Heroku and local repos. Decide which one you want to stick with (it will depend a lot on which framework you use for development) and use this one in both production and local repositories.

The workflow is always exactly as you mention it. If you can, it is recommended to set up your local machine to do most of the testing there (so you won't have to push to Heroku each time). Read also about Foreman (https://github.com/ddollar/foreman)!

In this post (our blog) you will find an easy and complete introduction to Heroku that might be really helpful (I hope!): http://blog.chattyhive.com/2014/08/chattyhive-made-part-2-heroku/

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Using version control is much much better than editing a file on the server "live" and see its effect immediately. Heroku adheres to some software development protocols which will benefit you in the long term, and using version control is one of those.

Usual workflow includes:

`git add .
git commit -am "Message"
git push heroku master`

which isn't that much of an annoyance when you're used to it :-).

Regarding MySQL, you can use MySQL on Heroku ([info](https://addons.heroku.com/cleardb)), it's just that MySQL isn't that natively supported like PostgreSQL.